# "une fratrie niveau garde"?

Tags: grammaire, sens

I saw this comment on reddit:

> je crois pas qu'à cet âge on puisse séparer une fratrie niveau garde.

Chatgpt helped me translate the last 3 words because I couldn't really make sense of it, and apparently it roughly means "I can't believe in this age that anyone would separate siblings through custody."

Is the sentence grammatically correct though, and if so, how? I can't figure out how "fratrie niveau garde" makes any sense, it seems like 3 nouns in a row.

Comment: I'm not really happy with *niveau* translated by "through" !

Comment: C'est pas beau ;-) On dirait que la personne qui dit ça manque un peu de vocabulaire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a non standard use of the word *niveau*, which I think is rather recent (let's say 21st century), it is colloquial and belongs more to spoken language than to written language.

*Niveau* here is used as a preposition (so, not as a noun), in correct written language we would say *en ce qui concerne* (possibly *pour ce qui est de*, which sounds slightly more informal).

> je (ne) crois pas qu'à cet âge on puisse séparer une fratrie en ce qui concerne la garde.

Comment: +1, you can also simply replace it with "au niveau de". I'm pretty sure it's older than 21st century though.

Comment: +1, also : je ne crois pas qu'à cet âge des mesures de placement puissent séparer une fratrie.